# Cannot install package python-guestfs

Tags: python, module, installation, package, ubuntu-11.10

I have ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric) I tried to run a program called snf-image-creator (it is for creating virtual machines)
and I get the error:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/snf-image-creator", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('snf-image-creator==0.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'snf-image-creator')()
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 351, in load_entry_point
def get_resource_filename(manager, resource_name):
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2363, in load_entry_point
def clone(self,**kw):
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/snf_image_creator-0.5.1-py2.7.egg/image_creator/main.py", line 42, in <module>
  from image_creator.disk import Disk
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/snf_image_creator-0.5.1-py2.7.egg/image_creator/disk.py", line 43, in <module>
from image_creator.image import Image
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/snf_image_creator-0.5.1-py2.7.egg/image_creator/image.py", line 41, in <module>
import guestfs
```

ImportError: No module named guestfs

So I tried to install guestfs. I used apt-get install python-guestfs
but I get message :

```
E: Unable to locate package python-guestfs
```

I also tied with apt-get install guestfs or libguestfs, python-libguestfs. I searched for the package in http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and there are results. I also used command

```
sudo apt-file find guestfs
```

but it didn't returned anything. Also command

```
 aptitude install libguestfs 
 aptitude install guestfs
```

and also because oneiric is not supported anymore I changed in /etc/apts/sources.list
the links to:

```
 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

and then I did

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 1):

11.10 has been unsupported for nearly a year now. You can try a source install, the instructions are in the project readme:

https://github.com/libguestfs/libguestfs

Comment: i have installed libguestfs-1.26.1 and everything went fine and when I run 

./run guestfish 
 
I have 
Welcome to guestfish, the guest filesystem shell for
editing virtual machine filesystems and disk images.

Type: 'help' for help on commands
      'man' to read the manual
      'quit' to quit the shell

><fs>

but I still get the error mentioned before

Answer (score 0):

If you have guestfs itself installed, then you should be able to download the Python source from github:

- https://github.com/libguestfs/libguestfs/tree/master/python

Then you can just do a Python source install. Something like this is usually all it takes:

```
python setup.py install
```

You may have to prepend that with sudo.

Comment: I forgot to mentrion that I have installed libguestfs-1.26.1  I used  ./configure then make and then make install and everything finished fine. But then I still had the problem mentioned before.

Comment: My guess is you have to install the Python bindings separately, which is what the above command will do if you run it against the setup.py file.

Comment: Ok I download it but I can't install it. make ./configure don't work. How do I install them?

Comment: ./autogen.sh should do the trick for making the configure script (it does mention it in the README, you know ;) )